# How can I find the radius of convergence $R$ of the power series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac {(-1)^n 2^{-n} z^{2n+1}} {n!}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I find the radius of convergence $R$ of the power series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} \frac {(-1)^n 2^{-n} z^{2n+1}} {n!}$ ? I've tried to get it onto the proper form $\sum^{\infty}_{n=0} a_n(z-a)^n$ without luck. I need this form to use the well-known formula for calculating the limit of the terms $a_n$ (ratio) ?

Answer (score 1):

Use ratio test for absolute convergence. You take directly the general term of the infinite series and think when the ratio test gives you convergence.Then check the endpoints.

Comment: but we have infinite many $a_n  = 0$ ? They cannot be $0$ for this test to work ?

Comment: Your general term without $z^(2n+1)$ is always nozero. How can you have infinitely many 0's?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alternating series test for any $R>0$. Thus the radius will be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

$$r = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left| \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}} \right|$$.

Comment: but $a_n \neq 0$ for this to work !

Comment: $a_n \ne 0$ here